# power transistors use in electric car

Tags: transistors

the battery rating is 48v and the motor in electric car rating is 3.28kW.h/100km. i will connect a power transistors with a microcontroller(output from micro controller only 5v) and also the motor. But the problem is i need a power transistor which can produce high current so that it can send to motor with power 3.28kw. Any suggestion that which power transistor is suitable to use? thanks.

Comment: Try looking for power mosfets

Comment: there is insufficient info to answer this question, "3.28kW.h/100km" doesn't tell us how much current the motor draws instantaneously.

Answer (score 2):

A 3.28 kW load at 48v draws (3280W/48v) 68.3 amps. This much current will need a beefy power-transistor.

If you request a suggestion for a specific model, I've build a motor driver with an "IRFP90N20D" power MOSFET.
This type of transistors doesn't have a fixed voltage drop between emitter en collector like BJT's but has a fixed ON-resistance (Rds-on). This specific model has an Rds-on of 0.023Ω which means it can handle up to 94 amps (If properly heat-sinked!). Keep in mind that your motor can draw current peaks in excess of the 68.3 amps calculated above.

But if you would like to use this MOSFET you'll need a gate-driver. First of all, the 5v logic signal will not fully turn on the MOSFET. This will make it start dissipating a lot of heat if large load is applied! Secondly, you'll want to fully turn on and fully turn of the MOSFET as quickly as possible to avoid that region in between so it doesn't start dissipating heat again. A good gate driver accomplishes this and accepts your 5v logic signal as input. A good gate driver I used is the "TC4452" from Microchip.

Last of all: an electric motor is an inductive load. This means quickly turning off the current in an motor will cause a voltage spike. This can potentially damage the MOSFET. (A large current spike will flow through the MOSFET body diode.) To avoid this, a diode is placed parallel with the MOSFET body diode. Google "freewheeling diode" to learn more.

I hope these indications can help you on your way.

Comment: Since the rating as stated was "3.28kW.h/100km", your calculation is only correct for a speed of 100 km/hr.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there possible to use transistors but try to parallel many transistors to create high current?

Comment: A MOSFET is a Field Effect **Transistor**... So if your requirement is dictated by the English language, then you're good to go.